# SQLite and Flask - INSERT statement Error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

I am making a flask app that should make `insert` posts to an SQLite database. I have written the `.py` script that should make this work. When I run this script it inserts to the database. When I call this script from my flask app no error is returned but no row is inserted to the database.

---

`database.py`

```
import sqlite3


def db():

    database = 'database.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)  VALUES (data1, data2)"
    c.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print('Added to DB')
```

---

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/database')
def db_insert():
    database.db()
    print('TEST')
    return render_template('display.html')
```

---

The print statements run so the console will show "Added to DB" but no row will actually be inserted.

I initially forgot the `.commit()` but fixing that caused it to work when running direct from `database.py` but still not from flask.

Comment: What are the `data1` and `data2` variables set to?

Comment: Is `Added to DB` being printed when you hit the flask route? This is another way of asking are you sure the function is being hit through the flask route and just not inserting/saving to db, or is it possible the function isn't being run at all?

Comment: Yes the print statement is returned - the function is being called correctly from flask but no rows are added.